# Microsoft Access update specific table column with select query data

Tags: sql, ms-access

I currently try to update one table with the data from a select query in Microsoft Access. I have went through alot of threads, forums and topics in the past three hours and nothing that I tried worked. I am relatively new to SQL so it makes it even harder.

Important things I have found so far:

- In regular sql when using where/like you use % whilst I have to use * in Microsoft Access (cant confirm this since my update doesnt work)
- There is an @ symbol one can put infront of the variable name after SET (not sure what this does but it said something about dynamic updates)

Consider these simplified Tables

This one is supposed to receive the update

```
|   Date      |  Login  |
----------------------
|  5.01.2018  |         |
|  4.01.2018  |         |
|  3.01.2018  |         |
|  2.01.2018  |         |
|  1.01.2018  |         |
```

This one is supposed to supply the data

```
|   User   | Attemps |
----------------------
|  Guest5  |    2    |
|  CEO     |    4    |
|  IGuest2 |    6    |
|  Guest1  |    7    |
|  NoGuest |    8    |
```

I currently attempt to Update the Login value with the amount of users trying to login with a username containing Guest, these would be the ones marked with * below which adds up to a total of 4

This would be:

```
|   User   | Attemps |
----------------------
|  Guest5  |    2    |  *
|  CEO     |    4    |
|  IGuest2 |    6    |  *
|  Guest1  |    7    |  *
|  NoGuest |    8    |  *
```

Lets say this table was from today (05.01.2018) now I would like to update my other table with that data so I would get a table looking like this

```
|   Date      |  Login  |
----------------------
|  5.01.2018  |    4    |
|  4.01.2018  |         |
|  3.01.2018  |         |
|  2.01.2018  |         |
|  1.01.2018  |         |
```

So far I have went through a dozen of Forum posts and I managed to actually set a value but not by selecting it from another table.
For example this works fine:

```
UPDATE [Test]
SET [Test].[Login] = 4
WHERE (((Test.Date)=Date()));
```

While when I try to Update them with actual table data e.g.

1.

```
UPDATE [Test]
SET [Test].[Login] = SUM( CASE WHEN [Sheet].[User] LIKE '*Guest*' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
WHERE (((Test.Date)=Date()));
```

2.

```
UPDATE [Test]
SET [Test].[Login] = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Sheet].[User] WHERE User LIKE '*Guest*')
WHERE (((Test.Date)=Date()));
```

I am always faced with

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

---

I will use this below as a representation of what I currently got and which error  it gives me:

```
UPDATE [Test]
SET [Test].[Login] = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Sheet].[User] WHERE [User] LIKE "*Guest*")
WHERE (((Test.Date)=Date()));
```

Could not find $PATH_HERE..

My Sheet is listed under Queries and not Tables if that makes a difference?

Comment: While your Access syntax is probably off, I also don't understand the logic behind your updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you get the syntax right, you will be met with

> Operation must use an updateable query

because the subquery uses an aggregate and thus is read-only.

Use Domain functions (here [`DCount`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dcount-function-f6b5d78b-ad0b-4e42-be7a-11a64acbf3d3)) for this:

```
UPDATE [Test]
SET [Test].[Login] = DCount("*", "[Sheet]", "[User] LIKE '*Guest*'")
WHERE Test.[Date] = Date();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are reading posts related to TSQL, which is SQL Server's flavour,  instead of MS Access SQL.

Aside from the wildcard differences (MS Access uses * and ? instead of TSQL's % and _) you also need to enclose strings in double quotes "" instead of TSQL's single quotes.

try this:

```
UPDATE [Test]
SET [Test].[Login] = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Sheet].[User] WHERE User LIKE "*Guest*")
WHERE (((Test.Date)=Date()));
```

Comment: Access works fine with single quotes too. But `User` is a [Reserved word](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845663.aspx) and must be escaped with square brackets.

Comment: Hey Stephen, thanks for the quick response! I have edited my query and put User into square brackets as Andre said. I now get another error and I'll update my post now.

Comment: If you have a new issue, please don't edit your post. Ask a new question and leave this one here for others who may have the same problem.